# Mount a local folder into docker container running in a VM

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following scenario:

Docker CLI is running on my machine.

There is a remote VM running the docker demon inside. The API is exposed. My local Docker CLI connects to the docker demon inside the VM.

I have my project folder on my local machine. When I run a docker build, the files from my local folder are correctly sent to the docker demon in the VM and used to build an image.

However, when I run the image, I also want to mount my local project folder into the docker container running in the VM so I can make changes and see the results. This seems to be impossible - I seem to be only able to mount folders from my VM into the docker image.

Comment: I am assuming you are using Virtualbox. You can mount the share folder in your VM. And then you can attach this folder to the Docker container in the VM. For more further reading on mounting share folder in VM https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#sharedfolders

Comment: No, the VM is running in the cloud. Thats why I wrote its remote.

Comment: And just to clarify: right now, I am mounting a local folder via SSH into the VM to mount it into the docker container from there. I want to drop that workaround :)